# Using JSON markers in Google Maps API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, maps

I am quite new to programming, so I'm a little scared to post. But I've been working on something that's likely quite simple for most of you for two days and thought I'd try here...

I am trying to create markers in the Google Maps API.

If I hard code the data into javascript, like this, it works like a charm.

```
var locations = [
['1 Bedroom House', 55.1111, -100.1111, 1, 'This house has 1 bedroom.'],
['2 Bedroom House', 56.1111, -100.1111, 2, 'This house has 2 bedrooms.'],
['3 Bedroom House', 57.1111, -100.1111, 3, 'This house has 3 bedrooms.'],
['4 Bedroom House', 58.1111, -100.1111, 4, 'This house has 4 bedrooms.']
];
```

I have a JSON request and need to get the marker data from there instead.

Before you say it, I'm sure I'm WAY off on here... but this is what I got:

```
var locations = new Array();

$.getJSON("[URL]", function(json) {
        for(var i = 0; i < json.houses.length; i++) {
            var name = json.houses[i].house.name;
            var markerlat = json.houses[i].house.lat;
            var markerlng = json.houses[i].house.lng;
            var description = json.houses[i].house.description;

locations[i] = new Array();
locations[i].push('\'' + name + '\', ' + markerlat + ', ' + markerlng + ', ' + i + ', ' + '\'' + description + '\'');

}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `But I've been working on something that's likely quite simple for most of you for two days and thought I'd try here`. These are exactly what our community likes to see. Even though you're new to programming, your question shows that you've done your research and have attempted to solve the problem yourself. +1 on your question, and looking forward to seeing you contribute more to Stackoverflow in the future!

Comment: one thing you did forget is to post what error messages you're seeing. Can you **edit** your question and add that information to the question body as well? I also want to add that your Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug has a NET tab where you can see the response you're getting from the server. Make sure you're getting the data in the correct format. Please post that in your question as well, if you can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at that part of your code, I wonder if it could be solved without the separate locations array.

Could it work if you extend the *for* loop in the success handler of the $.getJSON function with following kind of code:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerlat, markerlng),
    title: name,
    map: [id of the map canvas element]
    });
```

If you want to have the descriptions also available, you'll have to attach listeners to the markers that trigger info windows. More details of the Info Window overlays and their usage can be found from [Google Maps API documentation site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).